# Degrees of separation using Freebase and MQL?

Tags: freebase, mql

I`ve been examining Freebase and some queries like this:

[Retrieving/storing All related Actors in Freebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135491/retrieving-storing-all-related-actors-in-freebase)

and I`ve come up with an idea of finding out degrees of separation between chosen actors. Is there a way to make MQL find a link (by other actors that co-starred in a movie) between for example 'John Wayne' and 'Daniel Craig'?

Answer (score 1):

I may be a little late to answer, but recently I came across an excellent tutorial from GraphLab that seems to do exactly what you're describing. Check out:

http://graphlab.com/learn/notebooks/graph_analytics_movies.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a thread](http://freebase.markmail.org/thread/obvnkfg7rkakzvip) from the Freebase mailing list that discusses an app that did Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon. Its actually pretty difficult to do this with the MQL API because after you get a couple of degrees apart the queries start to time out.

I'd recommend that you download the [Freebase data dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) and calculate all of the [shortest paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path) between every actor in Freebase offline. You can then save all those paths and query them quickly from your app. If you [use grep to filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263401/text-file-of-all-titles-topic-titles-in-freebase/18265006) the data dumps down to just [the relationships between actors and movies](https://www.freebase.com/film/performance?schema), then the data should be small enough to run the whole search in memory on a desktop/laptop.

Comment: Thank you Shawn for your all-embracing answer! I`ll try to cope with your solution and hope it works.